How to specify a specific protocol in an array of protocols
I have a protocol, which has a property that is another protocol. I have a few structs that implement that protocol and I'm happy with them. However, I would like to have an array of the protocol, but specify that the inner protocol is always a specific type.
It is probably easier if I show some example code:
protocol MyCategory {
    var displayTitle: String {get}
}

enum Category1: MyCategory {
    case person
    case place
    case thing
    
    var displayTitle: String {
        switch self {
           ...
        }
    }
}
enum Category2: MyCategory {
    case animal
    case vegetable
    case mineral
    
    var displayTitle: String {
        switch self {
           ...
        }
    }
}

protocol FieldModel {
    var category: MyCategory { get }
    var name: String { get }
}

struct IntFieldModel: FieldModel {
    let category: MyCategory
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}

struct StringFieldModel: FieldModel {
    let category: MyCategory
    let name: String
    let value: String
}

struct Category1ConsolidatedResults {
    let fields: [FieldModel]
}

I would like to be able to tell Category1ConsolidatedResults that every item in fields will be of type FieldModel but also that every category in that every FieldModel will be of type Category1.
I tried to do something with generics and associatedtype but I couldn't figure out how to pass the type into the FieldModel protocol in Category1ConsolidatedResults. Instead I got the error "Use of protocol 'FieldModel' as a type must be written 'any FieldModel'".
Is there a way to pass a type to a generic protocol?

Then you need create another new protocol or type, where category is Category1.

You should indeed add an associated type to FieldModel, so that category information is encoded into the type system. In addition to that, you can make this the primary associated type of FieldModel, so that in Category1ConsolidatedResults, you can write [any FieldModel<Category1>].
protocol FieldModel<Category> {
    associatedtype Category: MyCategory
    var category: Category { get }
    var name: String { get }
}

struct IntFieldModel<Category: MyCategory>: FieldModel {
    let category: Category
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}

struct StringFieldModel<Category: MyCategory>: FieldModel {
    let category: Category
    let name: String
    let value: String
}

struct Category1ConsolidatedResults {
    let fields: [any FieldModel<Category1>]
}

struct Category1ConsolidatedResults {
    let fields: [any FieldModel<Category1>]
}

Also consider writing a ConsolidatedResults type, generic over the category type:
struct ConsolidatedResults<Category: MyCategory> {
    let fields: [any FieldModel<Category>]
}


You're right when you tried to use associatedtype in this scenario. However, I believe you're missing constraints on Category1ConsolidatedResults. You can try this approach:
protocol FieldModel {
    associatedtype Category: MyCategory //<- here
    var category: Category { get }
    var name: String { get }
}

And then add generic constraints on these Field models implementation:
struct IntFieldModel<Category: MyCategory>: FieldModel {
    let category: Category
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}
...

Finally, Category1ConsolidatedResults needs all the fields is FieldModel and also MyCategory is Category1.
struct Category1ConsolidatedResults<T: FieldModel> where T.Category == Category1 {
    let fields: [T]
}


Now you're able to tie Category1ConsolidatedResults with Category1 anytime it is defined.
//Any other MyCategory, such as Category2 will cause a compile error
let result = Category1ConsolidatedResults<IntFieldModel<Category1>>(fields: [
    .init(category: Category1.person, name: "", value: 1),
    ...
])


I was excited to try this approach and it may work well for some people but I found issues with it. E.g. Any reference to Category1ConsolidateResults requires me to specify Category1ConsolidatedResults<FieldModel<Category1>> (but I suppose a typealias would solve that.)
Also, I kept having to use as! T when adding anything to the array.
The code was not feeling clean.

The type must be defined here because of the constraint requirements. IMO, a typealias here doesn't make sense, generic is kind of a placeholder at compile time and will be filled at run time. As you mentioned, as! T doesn't require at all if you declare append function inside Category1ConsolidatedResults. i,e: mutating func append(_ element: T) {  fields.append(element) }. I am assuming you want a type-erased inside Category1ConsolidatedResults, right? or does it need to be an array of Any?
